# Changing and displaying user password on app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I know that it is possible to reset a user's password by sending a password email reset with firebase. But is there a way to reset the password on the app? And also display the user's password?
Looking for a solution in react.

Comment: You can change a users password with [updatePassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatepassword)

Comment: Is there a way of displaying users password?

Comment: Displaying an insensitive password to a user is a very big security hole. There isn't a supported way to get it in free text and display it to the user.

Comment: But, to ensure security, is there a way to at least verify that the user knows their password in order to be able to reset their password?

Comment: As part of the updatePassword function, the user must have a fresh security token. In the documentation I linked: "Important: this is a security sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in." You can also force the user to refresh their token using the reauthenticate functions like [reauthenticateWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential)